# Autoexp.dat Versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm working on a project where I need switch between a couple of different (incompatible) autoexp.dat files.  Currently, that involves closing all instances of Visual Studio, copying the file I want to the new location, and then opening Visual Studio again.  Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe a command line option to specify the location of autoexp.dat?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to run two instances of Visual Studio at the same time, with each using a different autoexp.dat file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what you suggest? I know there is a way to make it a plugin to visual studio, as mentioned [Here](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/06/11/extend_visual_studio/). Perhaps you could modify this setup to dynamically load the autoexp.dat file you want to use?

Comment: The trouble with that solution is that it patches the actual file on disk.  That means that I couldn't have two instances of visual studio open at the same time with different autoexp.dat files.

Comment: Seems pretty trivial to create a few different versions of the autoexp.dat file and just patch the autoexp.dat to the specific version you are using.

Comment: That may work.  The trouble is that I'm not sure when visual studio parses the file?  Is it at start up?  When you begin debugging?  If it's just before you begin debugging it, then it will probably work.